# Undefined class with ES6 and Sails.js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am developing a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) app. I am using using [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) `v4.2.1`. I am trying to write a class which should be called within my api.

In my controller, I have written

```
'use strict';

class Sample {
    disp() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

module.exports.Sample = Sample;
```

In my api, I am trying to use

```
//Included the class file above the controller.
//var Sample = require('../repositories/ExampleRespository.js');
test: function (req, res) {
    var sample = new Sample();
}
```

`Sample` seems to be undefined.

I have tried `module.exports = Sample;` I am still facing the same error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Apologies if the question is silly.

Comment: How do you include the class file into your API?

Comment: I have updated my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exporting `Sample` as the default, so your import should look like this:

```
var Sample = require('../repositories/example.js');

test: function (req, res) {
    var sample = new Sample();
    ...
}
```

Either that, or export it as `Sample`:

```
module.exports.Sample = Sample;
```

**EDIT**: so, to be clear:

One solution:

```
// example.js
...
module.exports = Sample;

// API file
var Sample = require('../repositories/example');
```

Another solution:

```
// example.js
...
module.exports.Sample = Sample;

// API file
var Sample = require('../repositories/example').Sample;
```

Comment: I have edited my post as per your answer. I get an error saying TypeError: Sample is not a function

Comment: @JaseemAbbas I edited my answer to clarify the two solutions I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your export statement should be:

`module.exports = Sample;`

Then you will be able to:

`var Sample = require('../repositories/example');`

*Note: you do not need .js on the end of a require statement.*